# W3C validator unable to find link in Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, w3c, razorengine

I am using MVC4 project and doing URL rewrite on Server side in RouteConfig and appending .html at the end of url of every page..

```
www.mysite.com/home.html
```

I have couple of pages and those pages are linked with home page (every think is working find in browser).

But when i validate using W3C link checker, i get broken link error message.

I really don't know what can be issue. One more thing if i replace `.html` with `.aspx` or any other extension it is validated by W3C. I don't know what is issue.

**My code is**:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "features",
                url: "features.html",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "features", page =    UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

**Web.config**  :

```
"<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />"
```

any help is highly appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [W3C Validation Not working for RazorView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096868/w3c-validation-not-working-for-razorview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
I replaced


<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" 
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />


with 


<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="*" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />

and it works :) 

now My page is validated by W3C.
```