# W3C Validation Not working for RazorView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, w3c, w3c-validation

I am using MVC4 project and doing URL rewrite on Server side in `RouteConfig` and appending `.html` at the end of url of every page..

```
www.mysite.com/home.html
```

I have couple of pages and those pages are linked with home page (every think is working find in browser).

But when I validate using W3C link checker, I get broken link error message.

I really don't know what can be issue. One more thing if I replace `.html` with `.aspx` or any other extension it is validated by W3C. I don't know what is issue.

My code is:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "features",
                url: "features.html",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "features", page =    UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

`Web.config`:

```
<add name="HtmlFileHandler" path="*.html" verb="GET" 
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved it some what like this.

I replaced

```
<add name="HtmlFileHandler" 
     path="*.html" 
     verb="GET"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
```

in webconfig with

```
<add name="HtmlFileHandler" 
     path="*.html" 
     verb="*" 
     type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" />
```

and it works ... my page is validated by W3C now. :)